# How to force to fill missing fields in profile in Joomla

Tags: joomla

In the site I develop, users can login to my website using facebook/google login.. Once the user login I want to prompt the user to update his profile with mobile number and verify it. In the backend I keep a field in DB which says whether the mobile number is verified or not.
So if the mobile number is not verified; for every login I want to prompt the user.

I tried profile completeness/force complete profile.. But couldnt achieve what I needed..

Any help appreciated..

Comment: Have you tried searching on the Joomla Extensions Directory for something that might suit your needs?

Comment: yeah .. From there I got two extensions profile completeness/force complete profile.. But it didnt help

Comment: Since normally on login users wouldn't be editing their profiles, I don't see how changing the profile would work unless you are forcibly redirecting on login. In which case, why not just do that using a plugin that uses the successful login event?

Comment: I am completely new to Joomla development. Could you plesae suggest me a plugin to do that..I tried but I couldnt find one or may be I didnt realize that it will solve my problem..